# Переопределение метода с произвольным числом параметров

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

Можно ли в родительском классе определить некий метод, чтоб у разных потомков для него было разное число входных параметров? Пусть считается, например, что этих параметров может быть лишь 3, 4 или 5, они имеют заранее известный тип (в моём случае это один int (число последующих параметов, от него я хочу избавиться) и 2-4 параметра созданного мной типа Particle); возвращаемое значение имеет тип float. То есть, хотелось бы, например, сделать так:

```
class PotentialAbstract {
public:
    virtual float E(int particlesNumberInFormula, ...) = 0;
};

// потомок, метод которого зависит от трёх параметров
class PotentialForBond : public PotentialAbstract {
public:
    float E(int particlesNumberInFormula, Particle p1, Particle p2);
}

// потомок, метод которого зависит от четырёх параметров
class PotentialForAngle : public PotentialAbstract {
public:
    float E(int particlesNumberInFormula, Particle p1, Particle p2, Particle p3);
}

// и так далее
```

Переменная particlesNumberInFormula при этом мне, вообще-то, не нужна, потому что каждый потенциал и без неё знает, от какого числа частиц он зависит. Просто, как я понял, для разбора параметров в вызванном методе нужно получать адрес первого из них, только поэтому передаю такую переменную в метод. Далее приходится работать с сырыми указателями, при использовании shared_ptr как действовать - мне неясно. В идеале хотелось бы идею ещё и быстро работающего способа. К примеру, как мне кажется, использование std::vector в качестве входного параметра будет медленным (или я неправ?). Ну и просто из любопытства: можно ли сделать потомков с разным числом входных параметров в переопределяемом одном и том же методе? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вообще, пишу программу расчёта молекулярной динамики, цель - тренировка в ООП. Но вот в вопросе расчёта потенциала, для чего я делаю данные классы, хотелось бы получить максимальную скорость. Понятно, что потом у меня будут проблемы другого рода. Но вот такой вопрос возник, теперь в любом случае интересно узнать ответ.

Comment: Нельзя, конечно. А как вы собираетесь его вызывать, имея указатель на базовый класс?

Comment: Гм, действительно, не знаю, как. Спасибо. Чего-то даже и не подумал об этом. Ну у меня низковат уровень владения C++, поэтому бывают глупые вопросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте std::vector, просто передавайте его по ссылке или указателю для избежания лишних копирований. Не думаю что он может оказаться "узким местом" в Вашей программе.

Comment: То есть, лучше ещё так делать: vector <Particle> v;
v.reserve(2); // ну или не 2, а 3 или 4?  
Просто я читал, что память выделяется сразу под несколько элементов. Ну и естественно, раз я заранее знаю, что у меня не больше четырёх элементов в векторе, то хотелось бы, чтоб лишняя память не выделялась.

Comment: Память выделяется по мере заполнения вектора. Да, Вы можете заранее зарезервировать место под все элементы, если известно сколько их будет. Но снова же, это могло бы избавить от лишних аллокаций памяти и принести какой-то прирост производительности на  большом количестве элементов, ~100к. При количестве в 4, Вы скорее всего ничего не заметите.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!